# Discord.JS addField in foreach not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For some reason, the addField is not working. No errors, it is just not showing up.

The query and foreach are fine and they work. I use that exact setup in a command. It's just not working for the embed.

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "",
database: "testbot"
});
con.connect(err => {
if(err) throw err;
console.log("Connected to database!");
});


function statusUpdate() {

var update = bot.channels.get('5777623821454355545');
const statusEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
statusEmbed.setTitle("**Current Statuss:**");
con.query("SELECT * FROM games", function(err, result, fields) {
   if(err) throw err;
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
        var row = result[key];
        statusEmbed.addField('**' + row.name + '**' + ' - ' + '(' + row.description + ')' + ' - ' + '**' + row.status + '**');
    });
});
update.send(statusEmbed);
}

bot.on('ready', () => {
console.log('This bot is online!');
statusUpdate();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the update of `statusEmbed` inside of the query callback, because if you don't you will update it when the `addField` will not be performed yet.

callback means that the query is asynchronous.

---

**Callback based soluce**

```
function statusUpdate(callback) {
  const update = bot.channels.get('577762382164525066');

  const statusEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();

  statusEmbed.setTitle('**Current Statuss:**');

  con.query('SELECT * FROM games', function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);

      return;
    }

    Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => {
      const row = result[key];

      statusEmbed.addField(`**${row.name}** - (${row.description}) - **${row.status}**`);
    });

    update.send(statusEmbed);

    callback(false);
  });
}
```

---

**Alternative**

```
function statusUpdate() {
  const update = bot.channels.get('577762382164525066');

  const statusEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();

  statusEmbed.setTitle('**Current Statuss:**');

  con.query('SELECT * FROM games', function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => {
      const row = result[key];

      statusEmbed.addField(`**${row.name}** - (${row.description}) - **${row.status}**`);
    });

    update.send(statusEmbed);
  });
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. You're answer just gave me an error of Callback is not a function

Comment: I added the bot.on('ready') to the bottom of the question, I forgot to show you that.

Comment: The `bot.onReady` is irrelevant in this matter. In my soluce you have to pass a callback to `statusUpdate`, I'll add an example without

Comment: Hmm, alright. I added your answer, and I just get the error callback is not a function

Comment: EDIT*** Nvm, first answer worked now. Sorry about that, thanks for the help.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq If you feel this answer solves your question, make sure to mark it as accepted.